# UPDATE doesnt use Model save method

Tags: python, django

If I do the folllowing:

```
obj = Model.objects.get(pk=2)
object.field = 'new value'
object.save()
```

It runs the custom save method that I have written in django.

However, if I do a normal update statement:

```
Model.objects.filter(pk=2).update(field='new value')
```

It does not use the custom save method. My question here is two-fold:

- 1) Why was that decision made in django -- why doesn't every 'save' implement the custom save method.
- 2) Is there a codebase-wide way to make sure that no `update` statements are ever made? Basically, I just want to ensure that the custom save method is *always* run whenever doing a save within the django ORM. How would this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Django developer, but I dabble from time to time and no one else has answered yet.

> Why was that decision made in django -- why doesn't every 'save' implement the custom save method.

I'm going to guess here that this is done as a speed optimization for the common case of just performing a bulk update.  [`update` works on the SQL level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) so it is potentially much faster than calling `save` on lots of objects, each one being its own database transaction.

> Is there a codebase-wide way to make sure that no update statements are ever made? Basically, I just want to ensure that the custom save method is always run whenever doing a save within the django ORM. How would this be possible?

You can use a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) with a custom QuerySet that raises some Exception whenever `update` is called.  Of course, you *can* always loop over the Queryset and call `save` on each object if you need the custom behavior.

#### Forbidding Update on a Model

```
from django.db import models

class NoUpdateQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    """Don't let people call update! Muahaha"""
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        # you should raise a more specific Exception.
        raise Exception('You shall not update; use save instead.')

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # setting the custom manager keeps people from calling update.
    objects = NoUpdateQuerySet.as_manager()
```

You would just need to set the NoUpdateQuerySet as a manager for each model you don't want to update.  I don't really think it's necessary to set a custom QuerySet though; if it were me I would just not call update, and loop through the objects that need to be saved whenever I need to.  You may find a time when you *want* to call update, and this would end up being *very* annoying.

#### Forbidding Update Project-Wide

If you **really really** decide you hate `update`, you can just monkey-patch the update method.  Then you can be completely certain it's not being called.   You can monkey-patch it in your project's `settings.py`, since you know that module will be imported:

```
def no_update(self, **kwargs):
    # probably want a more specific Exception
    raise Exception('NO UPDATING HERE')

from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
QuerySet.update = no_update
```

Note that the traceback will actually be pretty confusing, since it will point to a function in `settings.py`.  I'm not sure how much, if ever, `update` is used by other apps; this could have unintended consequences.